# selected tab in a menu

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-lists

I'm wondering about how I can have selected tabs in mvc3 razor

my menu code is ->

```
<ul id="iecMenu" class="zeroPadding">
   <li id="menuHome">@Html.ActionLink("Home","Index", "Home")</li>
   <li id="menuOverView">@Html.ActionLink("OverView","Trips", "Trip")</li>
   <li id="menuParse">@Html.ActionLink("Parse", "Create", "Day")</li>
   <li id="menuSettings">@Html.ActionLink("Settings", "Index", "Settings")</li>
</ul>
```

Is there a simple way to have one of those tabs selected, ps. there are sub pages as well but I only want one these Items to be selected.

Thanks
sushiBite

Comment: yes ended up using little bit of both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the ViewBag to create a small script.
So in each controller I created an constructor

```
public CurrencyFilterController()
{
    ViewBag.MenuItemScript = helper.createMenuItemScript("menuSettings");
}
```

The CreateMenuItemScript method ->

```
public string createMenuItemScript(string menuItem)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
    sb.AppendLine("$(document).ready(function () {");
    sb.AppendLine("$(\"#" + menuItem + "\").addClass(\"selected\")");
    sb.AppendLine("});");
    sb.AppendLine("</script>");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Then in my _Layout.cshtml

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.MenuItemScript)
```

This works like a charm :)

Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess you have a class you'd apply to the `li` to show a selecetd menu item and this is in your master page. The usual way to pass this along is through the `ViewBag` or `ViewData`. You can pass it from the Action

```
ViewBag.MenuItem = "menuHome";
```

and then the master page would read

```
<li id="menuHome" @ViewBag.MenuItem == "menuHome"? "class=\"selected"\"":"">@Html.ActionLink("Home","Index", "Home")</li>
```

Or you can get fancy and place it into an attribute (which inherits from the `ActionFilterAttribute`, which you could apply over both actions and controllers. Something else to consider is to make the menu choices into an enumeration, to have your code more strongly typed and not comparing strings.

Comment: Well yes that did not render properly but it gave my an idea how to do this "clean" and I am not familiar with ActionFilterAttribute :/